# Enable domain login on login screen

Tags: active-directory, likewise, domain-server

I installed `likewise-open` including the `likewise-open-gui` to join my company's domain. I entered my computername and domain in the gui, provided an administrator account to join, and it did say it was successfull.

However, after rebooting I still don't have an entry to login via the domain, only guest and my local user. Any idea what's wrong?

**Edit**: `su` to a windows user does work in terminal. So the basics are working, I just need to know how to get the login option for a domain login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acutally adding a `greeter-hide-users=true` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` was enough (it disables the history of users on the login screen and adds a field where you have to enter username and password).